# ingesting in azure eventhub fails every morning

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-eventhub

sending events to eventhub fails every early morning with the below message. I have masked the number, since I am not sure what is that number and for security reasons.(code and error below)

1. I consistently send ~240 events per minute of very small size, so that should not be the problem.
2. I have 2 partitions and 2 consumers for my eventhub
   Please let me know if any of you know the solution or need more info.
   Thanks!

Error:
Message :An error occurred during communication with 'XXXXX06f186e4bb89aea2d8959bXXXXX_GXX'. Check the connection information, then retry.

StackTrace : at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult1.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.FaultTolerantObject1.OnEndCreateInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager1.EndGetInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Amqp.AmqpMessageSender.OnEndOpen(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.ClientEntity.EndOpen(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OnEndCreateInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.SingletonManager1.EndGetInstance(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OpenOnceManagerAsyncResult1.OpenComplete(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.OpenOnceManagerAsyncResult1..ctor(OpenOnceManager openOnceManager, TimeSpan openTimeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Func3 beginOperation, EndOperation1 endOperation)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OpenOnceManager.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Func3 beginOperation, Action1 endOperation)
at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageSender.BeginSendEventData(TrackingContext trackingContext, IEnumerable1 eventDatas, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.EventHubSender.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0(AsyncCallback c, Object s) at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory1.FromAsyncImpl(Func3 beginMethod, Func2 endFunction, Action1 endAction, Object state, TaskCreationOptions creationOptions) at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.Parallel.TaskHelpers.CreateTask(Func3 begin, Action`1 end, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
Date :4/12/2017 2:48:17 AM

Code:
    EventHubClient deveventHubClient = 
    EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "EventHubName");

```
private async Task SendInBatch(IList<byte[]> source, Guid UUID)
{
List events = new List(source.Select(b => new EventData(b)));

    EventHubSender Partition0;
    EventHubSender Partition1;
    Partition0 = deveventHubClient.CreatePartitionedSender("0");
    Partition1 = deveventHubClient.CreatePartitionedSender("1");
    if (UUID.GetHashCode() % 2 == 0)
    {
        await Partition0.SendBatchAsync(events);
    }
    else
    {
        await Partition1.SendBatchAsync(events);
    }
    return Unit.Default;
}
```

Comment: Does this issue appear every morning? Do you try to use another event hub to test if same issue appear?

Comment: I tried 2 eventhubs, overnight 1 failed at ~2:40 AM and another at ~4:30 AM., and this happens consistently every day.

Answer (score 0):

**Short ANS**:

You are possibly experiencing transient error while sending. If you want absolutely highly available code - consider changing your code to `EventHubClient.sendBatchAsync(...)` instead of using `PartitionedSender.sendBatchAsync(...)` and get rid of `% 2` logic in your code.

**WHY**:

Imagine - EventHubs as a stream of `Events` on cloud/azure.

In a distributed environment - faults are bound to happen all the time, although probability is low - for ex: the VM hosting your EventHubs could restart, one of n/w gateways could fail and the connections might reset, the container hosting your code might experience high-load and our load balancing algo. might move it around etc.,

When faults happen, we want to enable our customers to be able to send to EventHubs without perceiving the fault. So, in-other-words, to offer high-availability to our customers, we exposed the notion of `partitions`.

When you are sending using `EventHubClient.sendBatchAsync(...)` - our **Gateway** will detect which eventhub partition is immediately available and will route the event to that Specific event hubs partition - if multiple partitions are available - it will round-robin (for ex: just like how you did using `%2`).

Simply put, no. of partitions of EventHubs determines the **degree of High-availability** of EventHubs. So, if you are sensitive to connection failures - consider moving out of creating a `PartitionedSender` and use `EventHubClient` to directly send events to EventHub.

Comment: This makes sense, but I have a requirement, while reading from eventhub I need to average data for a minute that is coming from 1 UUID.. If I use EventHubClient instead of specific partition to send data per UUID, I get 2 averages per minute (each from my 2 partitions) instead of 1. To avoid such situation, I have sent data of 1 UUID through 1 partition only using %2 logic.

Comment: To read from eventhub I am using IEventProcessor, and in OpenAsync method I am averaging like:
    stream.GroupBy(item => item.PartitionKey).Subscribe(group => group
                     .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)).Subscribe(buffer => {
                         aggregation.Aggregate(buffer);

Comment: Once you got the 2 values - how about getting the avg. of that avg.? In general, I wouldn't recommend Sending to a specific partition, if you are sensitive to send errors & latencies. The proven way is to send as fast as you can - and deal with the problem (of aggregation) down-stream.

Comment: How do you recommend to do average of those 2 values? since entire class implemented from IEventProcessor runs twice (once for each partition)

Comment: I don't have end2end context on the problem you are trying to solve here. Since, your question was about - Send reliability - I am trying to advice how can that be achieved..

Idea1: For the down stream EventProcessorImpl - create a Singleton instance of AverageCalculator & invoke this class in EventProcessorImpl.onProcessEvents. Handle aggregating averages in the AverageCalculator class.

Idea2: emit an intermediate event with timestamp from your streams and Join both streams of Partition1 & Partition2

Comment: comment continued... Some of our customers demand - very-high send reliability & very-low send latency numbers (send in the order of 10's of milliseconds) - for instance - if someone is using EventHubs to track/monitor their users "activity" - and completing the user request to their web-server only upon getting an ACK back for their "send to EventHubs" - their tolerance to Send failures is very low. If you fall in that bucket - sending to a specific partition of EventHub will only make it worse - &, you should consider this approach of - deferring the problem to downstream application...

Comment: Thanks. I used singleton method.